# Change domain root folder to a subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to change my domain from the server root to a specific folder.

I have tryied with .htaccess and virtualhost and I wasnt very successful.

What I want is that domain.com point to /path/to/folder instead of /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put these rules in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/path/to/folder%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/path/to/folder%{REQUEST_URI} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/path/to/folder%{REQUEST_URI} -l 
RewriteRule ^ /path/to/folder%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

But you *really* should just change this in your virtualhost config. There should be a directive called `DocumentRoot`, you just need to append `/path/to/folder` to the end of it.

Then, everywhere where there is a `<Directory>` container that accesses the old document root, also append that to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Jon's solution works. A quicker solution is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^path/to/folder/ /path/to/folder%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```